# rails command does not use homebrew ruby and only invoke `/usr/bin/ruby`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It feels like `rails` command would only invoke the ruby bin under `/usr/bin/ruby` and ignore the homebrew installed ruby. The bash/zshrc file has been set up as can be seen from `which ruby` output below. I can not use rails command to create a new rails project because of this. Can anyone help to point to the right configuration to change this behavior? Thanks!

```
➜  rails -v                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                              
    Rails 7 requires Ruby 2.7.0 or newer.                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                              
    You are running                                                                                                                                            
      ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                              
    Please upgrade to Ruby 2.7.0 or newer to continue.                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                              
➜  ruby -v                                                          
ruby 3.1.1p18 (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) [x86_64-darwin21]
➜  which -a ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
➜  which ruby   
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
➜  which -a rails
/usr/bin/rails
➜  which -a gem
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

Comment: It would be easier if you use something like rbenv or rvm to manage your ruby versions

Comment: @SreeramVenkitesh rbenv gave the same error

Comment: You should also post `which rails` and `which gem`. Both of those need to be correct in order for the full Ruby environment to work properly. It can get confusing quickly to set up properly, which is why people prefer to use one of the Ruby managers instead.

Comment: @Casper thanks! edited! so `which rails` only list `/usr/bin/rails` and `which gem` listed `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem` so it seems `gem` is following homebrew ruby and `rails` does not? any suggestion on this case?

Comment: What about `gem which rails`. Did you install rails with the `gem` command from `/usr/local/opt`? If so, there should be a `rails` command in `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin`. That's the one you want to run and not the one in `/usr/bin`.